# Mixing encapsulation and dependency injection

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection

I have a class that serves as a data model. I'll simplify it like this:

```
public class DataModel
{
   public bool IsDataModelActive {get; internal set;}
}
```

So the programmers who will use my DLL will only see what they need without risking to break anything.

On the flipside, I want to use DI in my classes that use `DataModel`. So I have to create an interface:

```
public interface IDataModel
{
   bool IsDataModelActive {get;}
}
```

And so I inject this in my class:

```
public class Class1
{
   IDataModel dataModel;

   public Class1(IDataModel dataModel)
   {
      this.dataModel = dataModel
   }
}
```

In this case, it is impossible for me to access the setter of dataModel.IsDataModelActive.

The best patch I've found is to cast after receiving the injection:

```
public class Class1
{
   DataModel dataModel;

   public Class1(IDataModel dataModel)
   {
      this.dataModel = (DataModel)dataModel
   }
}
```

This helps for the unit tests, but it kind of break the whole concept of DI. What if I have another class that implements `IDataModel`?

What strategy do you/would you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the interface IDataModel doesn't allow you to access the setter from outside of the DataModel, then (hopefully not surprisingly) you shouldn't *need to* access the setter from outside of the DataModel.  Either the DataModel itself or something that can see the setter should be responsible for setting that value.

Comment: That would make sens. So I have to choose between exposing my setters to the world and not using DI. That's unfortunate!

Comment: Or maybe it's just bad design on my side?

Comment: Just bad design probably (no offense).  What defines if `IsDataModelActive` should be true or false?

Comment: The DataModel should be returned as the result of a process, so It shouln't be instanciated by anything external to my code. So the IsDataModelActive will be modified by the process before it is returned.

Comment: In that case the interface that the *initialization process* uses should be an `IActivateableDataModel` or something like that, as suggested by @Sunny, and the interface passed to the users that don't need to set `IsDataModelActive` should be the `IDataModel` interface that you already have.  The `DataModel` class can and should implement both.

Answer (score 2):

Is Class1 publicly visible - i.e. exposed to the consumers? If not, then create another internal interface IDataModelInt : IDataModel and provide setter there. Use the second one for your internal work.

Comment: It seems to be the best idea. It forces me to send twice the same object (dependency) as two parameters, but it is a decent solution.